# How can I produce one bread every two seconds use multi-threading?

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to use the multi-threading to simulate produce breads in our company, I want to every two seconds produce one bread:

```
import threading
import time

def run(n):
    print ("product--%s" %n)
    time.sleep(2)

start_time = time.time()

for i in range(30):
    t = threading.Thread(target=run, args=("bread-%s"%i,))
    t.start()
```

But it seems do not pause two seconds, it direct print all all the breads:

```
product--bread-1
product--bread-2
product--bread-3
product--bread-4
product--bread-5
product--bread-6
product--bread-7
product--bread-8
product--bread-9
product--bread-10
product--bread-12
product--bread-11
product--bread-13
product--bread-14
product--bread-15
product--bread-16
product--bread-17
product--bread-18
product--bread-19
product--bread-20
product--bread-21
product--bread-22
product--bread-23
product--bread-24
product--bread-25
product--bread-26
product--bread-27
product--bread-28
product--bread-29
product--bread-30
```

The time.sleep did not works for me, how to realize my requirement? 
I want to every two seconds produce one bread, not one time produce all of them.

Comment: your code is set up to *immediately* print the bread argument, and *then* sleep 2 seconds. so, when you execute this code, all the threads rush to print `product--bread-x` and only after doing so, do they sleep.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains.

Answer (score 2):

From the [join() document](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/threading.html):

> **join**(timeout=None)
>
> Wait until the thread terminates. This blocks the calling thread until the thread whose join() method is called terminates – either normally or through an unhandled exception –, or until the optional timeout occurs.

You can use the `join()` to wait the thread execute, join every new started thread.

```
for i in range(30):
    t = threading.Thread(target=run, args=("bread-%s"%i,))
    t.start()
    t.join()
```